# Using System Environment variables in a sql script

Tags: sql-server

In a SQL script

```
GO
:setvar DefaultDataPath "%DataDrive%:\SQL\MSSQL\Data"
```

Will the script pick up %DataDrive% from the environment variables?
If not, is there a way to get to the DataDrive environment variable from the SQL script?

Comment: the easiest way is to run this throught `echo`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL server's `sqlcmd` supports script variables, which can be set in one of three ways:

- Locally in the script using `:setvar` as you do above
- Passed to the script using the `-v` option
- Set as environment variables before the script is run

In other words, you can replace `%DataDrive%` with $(DataDrive) in your script and either set DataDrive as an environment variable before running, or pass e.g. `-v DataDrive=D:\`.to your script when running with `sqlcmd`.