# Can I access environment variable inside a file

Tags: cmd

Here I'm setting the values in cmd.

```
cmd> set tb_name="student";
```

How to access it in a file in same window? Because I will run SQL file from cmd there I need to change table name,.

Comment: What about setting it as a global environment variable? (Question: Do you have admin rights to your computer?) By the way, A NEW cmd window will open, so you need to access variable `tb_name` there??

Comment: Yes it is admin user only. I want to use it in a same window

Comment: So, if you want to access it from the same window, you can access it with `%tb_name%`.

Comment: IMO you will have to rewrite the sql file (from a template). What sql version/environment, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208134/using-system-environment-variables-in-a-sql-script